# Hide/ Unhide query

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to find the button to `"unhide"` my Query after clicking on `"Hide"`. I've searched everyone online and there's literally no support for this.

Does anyone know where the unhide query button is?
[image: Attached image.]

Comment: Do you mean the query results window in SSMS? If so, `CTRL+R` toggles it. If not, which "hide" button did you click, and in which piece of software?

Comment: @Diado I've attached an image for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what the problem is. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or just click "Show Results Pane".

[image: Animated Gif]

Comment: It's not the "Hide Results Pane" I'm talking about. I'm talking about the "Hide" option which is greyed out for you in that gif. I clicked on that for one of my Querys and now I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: The `Hide` Button there is for windows other than the query pane, @Palwin. it's always disabled on the Query pane. if you select the Object Explorer, for example, and then go to `Window`, it's no longer disabled.

Comment: @Larnu There is a difference between "Hide" and "Hide Results Pane". Hide will *Hide* your Query which is happening in his case (Was trying to help  and even my Query is lost now, lol) and *Hide Results Pane* will just hide your output.

Curious where this damn thing is.

Comment: That's kind of my point though, @LifeOfJona, `Hide` when in a query window. Which makes me think the OP has done something *else*. :/